# Finding the maximum mean number of photons in a superposition of Fock states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

I am trying to find the maximum mean number of photons if $\beta$ (a complex number) is varied for the state $$|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{N_0}(|0\rangle + \beta |9\rangle).$$

I have normalised the state finding $$|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + |\beta|^2}}(|0\rangle + \beta |9\rangle).$$

I take the expectation value of $\hat N = \hat a^{\dagger} \hat a$ and find that $$\langle N \rangle = \frac{9 |\beta|^2}{1 + |\beta|^2}$$

Now, I want to vary $\beta$ to find the maximum mean number of photons.

I know how to find the maximum value of a function but I am uncertain about how I should be treating $|\beta|^2$ when I take it's derivative (due to it's complex nature). To illustrate my confusion, these are the two approaches I have considered for calculating $\frac{d|\beta|^2}{d\beta}$:

(1) $$\frac{d |\beta|^2}{d \beta} = 2|\beta|\frac{|\beta|}{\beta} = 2\frac{|\beta|^2}{\beta}$$

(2) $$\frac{d |\beta|^2}{d\beta} = \frac{d}{d\beta} \beta \beta^* = \beta^*$$

I haven't taken any complex analysis, but would really appreciate some guidance on how I should interpret this. Are either of these two approaches valid?

Comment: parametrise $\beta$ using (for example) its amplitude and phase: $\beta=r e^{i\theta}$ with $r,\theta\in\mathbb R$, compute the derivatives with respect to those, and impose them both to vanish. The reason you get inconsistent results taking the derivative like that you have to take some care differentiating wrt complex variables. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103993/173147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've formulated things in a way such that with your formalism you will never find the answer, but you're essentially overthinking this to the extreme.

The core answer is simple: if you're only looking for the expectation value of an operator that's diagonal in your chosen basis, then the only thing that matters is the population, and there is nothing quantum about it, i.e. you can just think of the problem as you would for a probabilistic mixture of $9$ photons with probability $p$ and $0$ photons with probability $1-p$. It is then easy to see that the expectation value is bounded as
$$
0\leq ⟨N⟩ \leq 9,
$$
with the extreme $⟨N⟩=9$ attained at $p=1$.

In terms of a quantum superposition, you could start by formulating your state as
$$
|\psi⟩ = \cos(\theta)|0⟩ + \sin(\theta)|9⟩,
$$
in which case you can find $⟨N⟩$ as a function and differentiate, and you will find an attained maximum at $\theta = \pi/2$, i.e. $|\psi⟩ = |9⟩$.

However, you have configured your initial Ansatz,
$$
|\psi⟩ = \frac{1}{N_0(\beta)}|0⟩ + \frac{\beta}{N_0(\beta)}|9⟩,
$$
in a way such that the amplitude of $|0⟩$ is always nonzero; this covers every state in the state space *except* the solution you're looking for. On the ground, that means that the solution you're trying to optimize,
$$
⟨N⟩ = \frac{9|\beta|^2}{1+|\beta|^2},
$$
never achieves its maximum, and it only converges to its supremum as $|\beta|\to\infty$.